# Class Errors with Pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, return, void

I'm currently writing a class for a program and this is what I'm attempting to accomplish...

1. Setup: Sets `m_ptrEmployee` to NULL and `m_beginHour` to hour.
2. AssignEmployee: Sets `m_ptrEmployee` to employee.
3. GetEmployeeName: Uses `m_ptrEmployee` and `Employee.GetName` to return the employees 
   name. Returns “UNALLOCATED”, if `m_ptrEmployee` is NULL.
4. Output: Uses `m_ptrEmployee` and `Employee.GetName` to display `m_beginHour` and the 
   employee’s name something like this, “8:00 - David Johnson” or like this, “8:00 -
   UNALLOCATED”, if `m_ptrEmployee` is NULL.
5. Reset: Resets `m_ptrEmployee` to NULL.
6. GetIsSet: Returns true, if `m_ptrEmployee` is not NULL and false otherwise.

Here is my code...

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "Employee.h"

class Schedule
{
    public:
    void Setup( int hour )
        {
            m_ptrEmployee = NULL;
            m_beginHour = hour;
        };
    void AssignEmployee( Employee* employee )
        {
            m_ptrEmployee = employee;
        };
    string GetEmployeeName()
        {
            if (m_ptrEmployee = NULL)
                return "UNALLOCATED"
            else
                return Employee.GetName()
        };
    void Output()
        {
            if (m_ptrEmployee = NULL)
                cout>> m_beginHour>>"--">>"UNALLOCATED">>endl;
            else
                cout>>m_beginHour>>"--">>GetName()>>endl;
        }
    void Reset()
        {
            m_ptrEmployee = NULL;
        }
    bool GetIsSet()
        {
            if (m_ptrEmployee != NULL)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    private:
    Employee* m_ptrEmployee;
    int m_beginHour;
};
```

`GetName()` is included in a previous class and it is...

```
public:
void Setup( const string& first, const string& last, float pay );
{
    m_firstName = first;
    m_lastName = last;
    m_payPerHour = pay;
    m_activeEmployee = true;
}

string GetName()
{
    return m_firstName+""+m_lastName
};
```

I'm receiving multiple errors and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? This is my first time attempting to write classes with pointers, so I apologize if my code is absolutely awful.

Comment: What are the errors you are receiving. Please paste them all.

Comment: FIRST THINGS FIRST, what are the errors? ALWAYS show the errors, you copy and paste as much output as you like! ALWAYS!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some corrections:

In general, be careful with comparisons in C++. You can't use the intuitive `=` when comparing two things. You have to use `==`. If you use `=`, it results in an assignment and not a test. Also, do not forget your semicolon `;` at the end of a statement.

Bad comparison:

```
if (m_ptrEmployee = NULL) //Assigns NULL to m_ptrEmployee and then tests m_ptrEmployee
                          //Always false because m_ptrEmployee was just assigned NULL
```

Good comparison:

```
if (m_ptrEmployee == NULL) //Better. This is false only when m_ptrEmployee equals NULL
```

When you want to access a member of a class through a pointer (such as m_ptrEmployee), you have to use the `->` operator like so: `m_ptrEmployee->GetName()`

Operator cout is used with the `<<` operator, and not the `>>` operator.

I have annotated the places in your code where you made mistakes.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "Employee.h"

class Schedule
{
    public:
    void Setup( int hour )
        {
            m_ptrEmployee = NULL;
            m_beginHour = hour;
        };
    void AssignEmployee( Employee* employee )
        {
            m_ptrEmployee = employee;
        };
    string GetEmployeeName()
        {
            if (m_ptrEmployee == NULL)   //Comparison always takes double ==
                return "UNALLOCATED";
            else
                return m_ptrEmployee->GetName();   //Use employee pointer with -> operator
        };
    void Output()
        {
            if (m_ptrEmployee == NULL)   //Careful with comparisons. Always use ==, not =
                cout << m_beginHour << "--" << "UNALLOCATED" << endl;  //Operator << was the other way around. It's not >>, but << for cout
            else
                cout << m_beginHour << "--" << m_ptrEmployee->GetName() << endl;
        }
    void Reset()
        {
            m_ptrEmployee = NULL;
        }
    bool GetIsSet()
        {
            if (m_ptrEmployee != NULL)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

    private:
    Employee* m_ptrEmployee;
    int m_beginHour;
};
```